# Graph de/serialization library supporting many formats

Tags: open-source, library, c++, graphs, serialization

I'm interested in a C++ library for reading and possibly writing graphs and digraphs from and to buffers and streams/files. In other words: A graph de/serialization library.

Required features:

- Supports at least a few commonly-used formats
- Gratis
- Libre
- Multi-platform (Linux, Windows, Mac)

Desired features (not in order of significance):

- Supports most/all common formats (say, something like [this list](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/)).
- Utilizes modern C++
- Has few or no dependencies (e.g. not Boost)
- Supports graph-like structures, e.g. graphs with ports
- Supports various non-basic features of the different formats (e.g. labels, coloring and grouping in graphviz).
- Actively maintained.
- Does not require building the graph in some library-specific format, but can accommodate your own format through iterators or templates.
- C bindings
- Can work entirely at compile-time if serializing/de-serializing from a buffer available at compile-time.